# GET Python request do not download file in comparison when pasting the same URL in a browser

Tags: python, file, download, request

I was researching how to perform a direct download from a website but I am having a very strange behavior. When I get the URL and I paste it  directly over the browser, automatically a file is downloaded. So I wanted to automatize this behavior and I opened the firefox inspect to see the exactly URL, method and headers. If I see the response in the inspect, a base64 string is visible (the content of the file). I wrote this code to reproduce it (for confidential reasons, I had to censor some data):

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode

URL_DOWNLOAD = "https://xxxx.xxxx.com.xx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?path=/xxxxxxx/999999999"

HEADERS = {"Host": "xxxx.xxxx.com.xx",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
           "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
           "Referer": "https://xxxx.xxxx.com.xx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?path=/xxxxxxx/999999999",
           "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx; xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
           "Connection": "keep-alive",
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}

print(URL_DOWNLOAD)
response = requests.get(url=URL_DOWNLOAD, headers=HEADERS)
print(response.content)
```

You can see I am printing the "URL_DOWNLOAD", when that string is copied to browser the file is automatically downloaded, but I expected the same data at `response.content` but I am getting a totally different message from the server. Do you know if I have to add some extra parameter to the request call?

Best regards!

Comment: It may be an issue with cookies